# Android App Crash. Putting JSON data into Listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, crash, android-asynctask

I just posted yesterday but now Im trying to take my data and put it into a ListView instead of a TextView. The app crashes after it brings up the listview activity. If anyone has any clue on this, help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres the activity code:

```
   package com.example.Accomplist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: DESAI_628IL
 * Date: 3/1/13
 * Time: 7:34 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class MainScreen extends ListActivity{
    JSONObject jsonObj= null;

    String[] eventArr= new String[10];
    int i=0;

   // HttpClient client;
    // url to make request
    String[] urlArr = new String[10];//"http://accomplist.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sharedevent/1/?format=json";


    //Following comment block is example of json object from above url
    {
    /*

    {
   "date":"2013-01-17T12:48:24.326859",
   "event":{
      "description":"I want to find work that I love so that I never have to work a day in my life.",
      "id":3,
      "resource_uri":"/api/v1/event/3/",
      "title":{
         "id":3,
         "listitem":"Get a Job I Enjoy",
         "resource_uri":"/api/v1/title/3/"
      },
      "user":{
         "date_joined":"2013-01-17T12:40:17.115755",
         "email":"sourabhdesai@gmail.com",
         "first_name":"",
         "id":3,
         "is_active":true,
         "is_staff":false,
         "is_superuser":false,
         "last_login":"2013-02-02T15:51:11.622505",
         "last_name":"",
         "password":"pbkdf2_sha256$10000$ETuiYJXQjvez$5yHd5IPaQpS0SvlissO/JydwXUHhMYDgadY7uyTyWg0=",
         "resource_uri":"/api/v1/user/3/",
         "username":"sourabhd"
      }
   },
   "id":2,
   "resource_uri":"/api/v1/sharedevent/2/",
   "votes":7
}

     */
    }
    private static final String TAG_EVENT="event"; //A JSON object within the JSON object that will be returned by JSONParse()
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION="description"; //A JSON tag within the JSON object EVENT
    private static String eventString="Yo";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        for(int b=0; b<urlArr.length; b++) {
            urlArr[b]= "http://accomplist.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sharedevent/"+(b+1)+"/?format=json";
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        ListView eventsList= getListView();
        new JSONParse().execute(urlArr[0],urlArr[1],urlArr[2],urlArr[3],urlArr[4],urlArr[5],urlArr[6],urlArr[7],urlArr[8]);
    }
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... jsonurl) {
//        StringBuilder url= new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(jsonurl));
        HttpUriRequest request= new HttpGet("http://accomplist.herokuapp.com/api/v1/sharedevent/2/?format=json");
        HttpResponse r= null;
        try {
            r = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        int status= r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status==200){
            HttpEntity e=r.getEntity();
            String data= null;
            try {
                data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
            try {
                JSONObject eventJson= jsonObj.getJSONObject(TAG_EVENT);
                eventString= eventJson.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            }
            catch (JSONException e1) {
                eventString="Couldn't Parse Data";
            }
            return eventString;
        }
        else{
            return eventString;
        }
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
        Toast loadingToast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        loadingToast.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        eventString=result;
        eventArr[i]=eventString;
        i++;
        MainScreen.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainScreen.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eventArr));

    }
}
}
```

And heres the LogCat error Messages:

```
02-26 15:57:21.692: WARN/InputMethodManagerService(324): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 5900 uid 10048
02-26 15:57:31.964: WARN/dalvikvm(5918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-26 15:57:32.042: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2143)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters,this line

```
eventsList= getListView();
```

should be inside your `onCreate()`. But declare `ListView eventsList` as a field variable as you are just initalize it in `onCreate()`

This is where your `NPE` is coming from since it gets the `ListView` from your `Layout` which you haven't got until you call `setContentView()` or `inflate` it with an `inflater`. So the call to `getListView()` will also need to come after `setContentView()`

You also will need a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"` in your `Layout`

I suggest going through the [ListActivity Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) because they can be a tricky thing until you understand them. I also suggest watching [Turbo Charge your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) which I believe I learned about through @Sam. This one is kind of old but still has a lot of good information. It deals with different parts of the `UI` but has good information regarding using a `ListView` more efficiently.

**Edit**

Just as it says here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Which is why I originally added this line in my answer :)

> You also will need a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"`
>   in your `Layout`

Like [The example from the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"  //this is the important part
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#00FF00"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried your suggestions and am still getting the same crashing error. I will take a look at your links and see if I can figure something out. Do you see anything else wrong?

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on now? You shouldn't be getting the same error if you inserted that code below where you inflate the layout holding the `ListView`. If you are I would try cleaning and check logcat for which line is giving the error

Comment: I just updated the LogCat error and my code above. It seems like it has an issue at line 90 which is simply my setContentView(R.layout.main_screen); line. Im really confused right now

Comment: I have update my answer. You need a `ListView` on which to call `getListView()`

Comment: Ok I changed my Id tag to the one you suggested. Now it is at least loading the activity with the ListView but it crashes before it displays any of my JSON data. The JSON data was displaying perfectly before when I was just putting it into a textview but it doesnt seem to work for a listview. Ive updated the LogCat above. Thanks for all your help so far, you've probably already saved me a few days worth of headaches.

Comment: I'm glad we were able to get you going. Since we fixed your first issue, I think you would be better off accepting this answer and starting a new post with the new logcat and relevant code. Otherwise, this post is going to get too cluttered and the answers won't be as useful to others. It will also help if you take out unnecessary comments so the code isn't as long and you are missing an important part of your logcat. It is showing a null pointer still but not the part where it shows which line of your class. If you post a new question and want me to look you can send me a link

Answer (score 0):

use `MainScreen` context for setting Adapter for `ListView` becuase you are extending `ListActivity` in `MainScreen` Activity as:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        eventString=result;
        eventArr[i]=eventString;
        i++;
        MainScreen.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainScreen.this, 
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,eventArr));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I put this into my code but to no avail. Im going to read up more on the docs for listview and see what other people did to parse JSON into a listview. But meanwhile, do you see anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: @sourdesi : use ArrayList instead of Array because array size is big u have declared 10 and adding only one Element in it inside onPostExecute